# Await StateObject initialization in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am working on an app that uses an `AVCaptureLayer` to display a video preview layer and also a text representation of the brightness (calculated from the video metadata). I've tried to make my app more efficient by only creating one `AVCaptureSession` in a class `VideoStream` and I want to then pass the capture session to a `UIViewRepresentable` that creates a `UIView` showing the video preview layer. The `View` is straightforward:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var videoStream = VideoStream() // holds session variable for AVCaptureSession
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VideoPreviewHolder(runningSession: videoStream.session) // videoStream.session not initialized at build time
        }.frame(width: 300, height: 300, alignment: .center)
        Text(String(format: "%.2f Lux", videoStream.luminosityReading))
            .font(.largeTitle)
    }
    
}
```

Does SwiftUI provide a way to await the initialization of a `StateObject` class? The `init()` method for `VideoStream()` calls a function responsible for first checking for camera authorization and if necessary requesting it, and if authorization is granted then a second function is called which configures the `AVCaptureSession`. This all takes quite a bit of time, especially if the user needs to grant or deny the authorization.

I've tried adding `await / async` to the `VideoStream()` initializer and the functions called therein, but since my `VideoStream()` class inherits from `NSObject`, I receive an error that `async initializer cannot be represented in Objective-C`.

Is there a SwiftUI specific way of awaiting the `StateObject`'s initialization?

Comment: It already *does* await the initialization of the `@StateObject`. What you must be looking for is awaiting something else async that is being dispatched inside the `init` of `VideoStream` (like asking for authorization). The code here is not enough to represent the issue.

Comment: I suggest using the alternative approach of **not** putting your (camera and configure) functions in the `init()` of `VideoStream`.
Put these in the `.onAppear{...}` or a `.task{...}` of the View instead. There, you can use the `await/async` if needed.

Comment: Use an ‘if let’ that way once session loads it will show the view, else’ can show a progress view or a message while the session is initialized. Using async await would require major work. (Based on your last question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `VideoStream`'s `session` property optional and published:

```
class VideoStream: ObservableObject {
    @Published var session: AVCaptureSession?

    // blah blah blah
}
```

Don't set the property until the session is fully configured. Make sure you dispatch back to the main queue/thread/actor to set it if needed.

Then make your view check whether the property is nil:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var videoStream = VideoStream()
    
    var body: some View {
        if let session = videoStream.session {
            VStack {
                VideoPreviewHolder(runningSession: session)
            }.frame(width: 300, height: 300, alignment: .center)
            Text(String(format: "%.2f Lux", videoStream.luminosityReading))
                .font(.largeTitle)
        } else {
            ProgressView()
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: This did the trick.  Small typo in @Published you may want to correct. Thanks for the solution.